# Comparing numbers from one array with indexing of another array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, element

just wanted to know if something like this can be done and how exactly. My aim is to take all the numbers from one array and compare them with the indexes of another one, finally print the elements.

Example:

```
var myindex = new Array(2, 0);

var array1 = new Array("text", "apple", "sample")
var array2 = new array("book", "phone", "orange")

myindex.forEach(number => document.write(array1.indexOf(number)))
```

Expected result: the following will be printed: sample orange text book

First issue: All that is shown is the -1 error which means I think: no number in the array but there is one so I do not understand?
Second issue: I also need to implement array2 to work together with array1 so we can actually see the expected result as shown above. I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through the index array and then use it's value:

```js
var myIndex = [2,0];
var array1 = new Array("text", "apple", "sample");
 var array2 = new Array("book", "phone", "orange");

for (var i = 0; i < myIndex.length; i++){
  console.log(array1[myIndex[i]] + " " + array2[myIndex[i]]);
}
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work in my .html and on that website as well: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgPJWM?editors=0010 /////that is exactly what I was trying to do yet it does not show up at all, just like with your code, can't see any errors

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array for the data and check if the data at the given index exist. Then make the output.

```js
var myindex = [2, 0],
    array = [["text", "apple", "sample"], ["book", "phone", "orange"]];

myindex.forEach(number => array[number] && console.log(array[number]));
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why it is not working at all here? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLPJxX?editors=0010 /// only works in 'snippet' editor on here.

Comment: i don't use console so much, but if you replace `console.log` with `document.write`, you get the wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `indexOf` here, which searches an array. You need to access the array via the *index* (square bracket notation) to get the value:

```js
var myindex = new Array(2, 0);

var array1 = new Array("text", "apple", "sample")
var array2 = new Array("book", "phone", "orange")

myindex.forEach(number => console.log(array1[number], array2[number]));
```

NB: You had a typo in the array constructor: it needs to be `Array()`, not `array()`. Secondly, don't use `document.write`.

Comment: thanks, really useful explanation on accessing indexes

Answer (score 0):

You just need to access the array elements with `array[index]` syntax.

```js
var myIndexs = [2, 0];

var array1 = ["text", "apple", "sample", "book"];
var array2 = ["book", "phone", "orange", "text"];

myIndexs.forEach((index) => document.write(`${array1[index]} ${array2[index]} `));
```

Plus, use `[]` syntax to create arrays and not `Array()`: https://coderwall.com/p/h4xm0w/why-never-use-new-array-in-javascript

If you want the results in two lines, well it kind of depends on your use case, you just really want to write to the html, you can simply do it like this:

```js
var myIndexs = [2, 0];

var array1 = ["text", "apple", "sample", "book"];
var array2 = ["book", "phone", "orange", "text"];

const results1 = [];
const results2 = [];

myIndexs.forEach((index) => {
  // Here you might want to validate if array1[index] exists
  results1.push(array1[index]);

  // Here you might want to validate if array2[index] exists
  results2.push(array2[index]);
});

document.write(`${results1}<br />${results2}`);
```

But, it might depend on your use case. I might want to create two different node targets in the html and write each of the results to different targets. You might just need the two array variables in javascript. You should not follow any of the code here blindly, you should adapt to your specific use case.

Comment: How about partial break line? I am looking for something like this:

(array 1 first row) = sample[2] text[0]
(array 2 second row) = orange[2] book[0]

Comment: That works like a charm, the thing is I was trying to modify the existing code to be within one line and I do not understand why it won't work. E.g. something like this:  //myIndexs.forEach((index) => document.write(`${array1[index]}<br />${array2[index]} `));   Since that didn't work, I have tried to manipulate your updated one and implement different methods as I cannot allow myself to create additional arrays unfortunately no luck. Just wondering if there's a way?

Comment: e.g. this will work but there are three lines, I need them to be one full line (adjusted accordingly, not just with spaces) and i'm not sure how to do it: 1. myIndexs.forEach((index) => document.write(`${array1[index]} `));
2. document.write("<br>");
3. myIndexs.forEach((index) => document.write(`${array2[index]} `));

Answer (score 0):

Just for some variety and for fun you may do like this;

```js
var myIndex = new Array(2, 0),
     array1 = new Array("text", "apple", "sample"),
     array2 = new Array("book", "phone", "orange");
console.log.apply(console, myIndex.reduce((p,c) => p.concat(array1[c],array2[c]),[]));
```